# To kill spark application

Tags: apache-spark, unix

I wanted to kill spark application id if its running for more than specific hours for eg. one hour. Is there a way possible to achieve in unix script running in particular user id. User id - application_user

```
yarn application -kill application_ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can propose the next solution:

1. You can parse the time when the application was started from the applicationId.
   (Use curl and Spark rest API to create a command to get application list and to take the correct applicationId: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html)
   After this step, you will have a date in format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS (For example 20181112020100)
2. Now you need to get the current time using the command: `date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`
3. In a cycle, get the current time and compare it with the time which you get from the first step which is application started time and compare it with the current time. When the difference between application started time and the current time will be, for example, two hours you will exit from a cycle and use kill command: `yarn application -kill application_ID`

Here is one of the realizations of proposed steps: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/86037/script-to-kill-yarn-application-if-it-is-running-m.html

Hope, this will be useful.